# Simultaneously scroll three iFrames containing PDF files

Tags: jquery, pdf, iframe, scroll

I have three iFrames in my html, each contain  PDF files. I need to be able to synchronize the scroll bar on the iframes so that the two smaller iframes on the left (#ifr2, #ifr3) scroll at half the rate as the first iframe (#ifr1). And also have the first iframe (#ifr1) scroll twice as fast as the other two iframes(#ifr2, #ifr3). These scroll events should occur when a user scrolls any of the iframes so that they remain constantly synced.

Here is my html:

```
    <iframe id='ifr1' width='400' height='600' src='pdf1.pdf'></iframe>
    <iframe id='ifr2' class='trans' width='400' height='300' src='pdf2.pdf'></iframe>
<iframe id='ifr3' class='trans' width='400' height='300' src='pdf3.pdf'></iframe>
```

Currently I am trying to do this via jQuery function, here is my code for that:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$("#ifr1").ready( function() {
   $("#ifr1").contents().scrollTop($("#ifr2").contents().scrollTop());
   $("#ifr1").contents().scrollTop($("#ifr3").contents().scrollTop());
});

$("#ifr2").ready( function() {
   $("#ifr2").contents().scrollTop($("#ifr1").contents().scrollTop());
   $("#ifr2").contents().scrollTop($("#ifr3").contents().scrollTop());
});

$("#ifr3").ready( function() {
   $("#ifr3").contents().scrollTop($("#ifr2").contents().scrollTop());
   $("#ifr3").contents().scrollTop($("#ifr1").contents().scrollTop());
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the code below can solve the problem.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
   $("#ifr1,#ifr2,#ifr3 ").scroll( function() {
     $("#ifr1").contents().scrollTop($(this).scrollTop())
   });
});
```

Your need put this code in the main page that have the three Iframe.

Comment: No unfortunately that didn't work - the iframes just didn't respond to the code